# Perl - Find last word in string including those with hyphens

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script that parses route tables from Cisco ASA5500 Network Devices.  I want to capture the last word in each line for further analysis.  A typical route table entry looks like...

C    123.201.2.12 255.255.255.252 is directly connected, outside

To get the last word in each line I use:

```
$line =~ /(\b\w*\s*$)/; 
  print $1."\n";
```

and it works fine most of the time.  But, some engineers put hyphens in the name, like dmoc-net. The output from this is just the word net. I see why this happens because the metacharacter \w* does not have a -,  it includes [a-zA-Z0-9_].  Is there a way to get the last word in a line including those with hyphens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one ?

```
$line =~ /(\b(\w|[-])*\s*$)/; 
   print $1."\n";
```

Explanation: You want your regex to match substrings composed of elements from the character class represented by `\w` and the character `-`. You cannot syntactically express that as a single character class in shorthand notation. However, you can always express a character class as an alternation between constituents of a partition of said character class ( though it usually makes no sense to do so; e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is equivalent to `([a-z]|[A-K]|[L-Z0-3]|[4-9]|_)` ).

Thus in your case you split up the conceptual character class `[{{\w}}-]` (invented ad hoc syntax) into `(\w|[-])`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @msrd0 you are perfectly right and i have heeded your advice.

Comment: Thanks collapsar!  I didn't even think about using | .  I was trying to just tack the hyphen on at the end.  This works fine!